# Significato e uso del termine "falorchia"

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Geremia non riusciva a credere alle **falorchie** che circolavano nel quartiere. Che la ragazza di Diamante, che Vita cosí adorabile e cosí adorata, potesse lasciarlo per quel delinquente di Rocco il quale fra l’altro non poteva sposarla perché aveva già sposato la figlia di Bongiorno – e infatuarsene al punto da fuggire con lui, era una cosa che non riusciva nemmeno a concepire.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato della parola "falorchia" che appare in questo passaggio? Non l'ho trovata sui dizionari che ho consultato. Si tratta di un termine di uso regionale?

Comment: Mi sembra un sinonimo di fandonie. Inoltre se cerchi il termine assonante _farlocco_ vedrai che è un sinonimo di falso, fasullo.

Answer (score 2):

Come ipotizzato nei commenti, significa *fandonia*.
Nel [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI24/GDLI_Supplemento_2009_321.pdf) si legge:

> **Falórchia,** sf. Fandonia, chiacchiera.
>  
>         [...]
>   
>         = Voce di etimo incerto, forse connessa con *farlocco*.

La parte omessa contiene appunto la citazione di Mazzucco che appare nella domanda.

Comment: Scusate perché ancora oggi a volte dimentico di ricercare sul GDLI, forse perché la ricerca non è affatto  comoda.

Comment: Questo [sito web](https://poetidelparco.it/amaseno-provincia-di-frosinone/) afferma che "falorchia" si trova sul *Lessico del dialetto di Amaseno* di Carlo Vignoli. Curiosamente, però, il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* non menziona che si tratti di un regionalismo o un dialettalismo. Madrelingua italiani: cosa ne pensate?

Comment: @Charo, grazie mille!